# How to have same state for all users?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react app which listens to a stream in real time. Whenever a new stream object comes in, I fetch it and append it to my state.
So a user will see all of the stream data since that user started streaming.

Now the problem is, if a second user starts streaming at some later time, he won't see any of the data which the first user has received.

I want to make one state common for all users. So that when they plug into my stream they see the same state.

How can i do that? I am using flask API which is providing me with the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the same stream for all users/browsers you cannot do it using the frontend only, because you don't have this information. You should look into the backend side to return the same data from your API.

That's why state management frontend libraries and other frontend tools will not help you, because it works only for this particular user.

Comment: Okay do you know how i can do that in backend? It is kind of like youtube/twitch live chat. It's same for all users. Any new user will be able to see previous comments

Comment: If you want to show all previous comments you should just send it from the backend, if you want to show video beginning with the particular time you should pass this time from the backend and on the frontend you will be able to show the same video for all users.

Comment: So i researched about this a little. i just want to know will this work. I will have one worker which will always listen to the stream and publish it to a redis channel. my react app will listen from this channel and show it to all users.

Comment: sounds like ok, you could try and if there are any questions create a new question on SO for the backend developers

Comment: @Georgy You give very abstract answer. Would rather do this as a comment. Author probably wants to check what websockets are, you need all clients to be connected to one channel, which says when something is updated, and next realod data and update state on all clients (related data and state)

Comment: And also rxjs, it can be used to show what already was streamed to new users.

Answer (score -2):

Quoting from [redux.org](https://redux.js.org/)

> Centralizing your application's state and logic enables powerful capabilities like undo/redo, state persistence, and much more.

I think this is what you are looking for creating a centralized state for your users :)

Comment: Redux can be used for creating a centralized state for all components. However, each user has its own Redux store, still.